# where to store user credentials in front end

Tags: asp.net, authentication, asp.net-web-api

in ASP.NET web API in the log in algorithm i have a action filter that generates a token for each user and the front end sends that token back to authenticate the user by using that token in web server i can get current user information till now every thing is working fine however i have new requirements that every user has relation many to many with account which means the same user can exists in more than one account with different roles for example in account one he is an admin in account two he is normal user so i have to regenerate the token which requires the user to re log in again i do not want him to be redirected to the log in page again. what i think of is to store user name and password in html 5 local storage but i think that is a bad practices any ideas. 
Her is how i generate token.

```
public override void OnActionExecuting(HttpActionContext actionContext)
{
    if (!actionContext.Request.Headers
           .Any(header => header.Key == "AuthorizationHeader"))
    {
        if (this.IsAnonymousAllowed(actionContext) == false)
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "Un Autherized");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        string token = actionContext.Request.Headers
         .Where(header => header.Key == "AuthorizationHeader")
         .First().Value.First();
        if (this.IsAnonymousAllowed(actionContext) == true)
        {
            return;
        }

        string passPhrase = System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["PassPhrase"];
        string ticket_string = Crypto.Decrypt(token, passPhrase);

        TicketData ticket = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TicketData>(ticket_string);

        if (ticket == null || ticket.Expiration < DateTime.Now)
        {
            actionContext.Response = actionContext.Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, "UnAuthorized");
        }
        else
        {
            OurIdentity identity = (OurIdentity)ticket.TokenData.OurIdentity;

            System.Threading.Thread.CurrentPrincipal = new OurPrincipal
            {
                OurIdentity = identity,
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right saving username and password in the local storage is bad. It is bad to save it anywhere on the client.

Usually a token is generated and put in a cookie. That token corresponds with a record on the server, in either a session log or a database.

I strongly suggest to use existing methods for this, like [OAUTH Bearer tokens in this tutorial](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/individual-accounts-in-web-api#authenticate).

Comment: i store the account id in the token but the user can change his account type without the need to be redirected which requires regeneration of new token

Comment: There is no need to do a redirect. Just do a background http request and renew the token.

Comment: So what should i do is to send request when account changes to a controller then edit the token and send it back to the front end. For give me i am new to asp.net

Comment: Just use a [jQuery post](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/) to send the request in the background to the controller and return the token. Save it in the local storage for example, or preferably a cookie.

Comment: thank you very much i have solved my problem by re generating the server token when account changes that solved the problem of storing user credentials on the client side.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I understand, if you are storing a hash (perhaps with a salt for extra protection) it is not nessecescarily bad to store the credentials.  These would have to be stored somewhere at the end of the day anyway.

Comment: But definitely not on the client.

Comment: I'd say that depends on how the server authenticates the client? I can see issues in cases where these can be taken and sent to the server at will by anyone but I don't otherwise.  Am I missing something important?

Comment: OP is talking about saving plain credentials (username / password) to a place (local storage) anyone can access who has access to the browser.